# Remove select placeholder on focus select field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

```
<select class="name">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Remove Select Option when user click on it like input field placeholder. Also not show in drop down.

Comment: where is `select placeholder`?

Comment: First option as use for placeholder

Answer (score 1):

```html
<select class="name">
    <option value="" style="display:none;">Select Option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

`style="display:none;"` should do the trick (Selected by default but not visible under options).

Answer (score 0):

You can instated use `<option value="" disabled selected>Select Option</option>`